# AngularJS tab content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How should i implement this:

4 tabs which open onclick and loads a view in to a child.

Tried with 4 ng-view tags and hiding 3 of them but it doesn't feel right. How should I display my content in the right tab?

```
<section id="tabs">
    <div class="tab open">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use bootstrap for a tabs and ng-include for a content
something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<!-------->
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <div ng-include src="'red.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
             <div ng-include src="'orange.html'"></div>                
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <div ng-include src="'yellow.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#tabs').tab();
    });
</script>    
</div> <!-- container -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Angular UI bootstrap module](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has all the twitter bootstrap components ported as angular modules. You should be using it instead of reinventing it (unless you cannot/dont want to use twitter bootstrap).

tldr: Try using bootstraps tabs component from angular UI bootstrap